# Python Psutil - verificar execução pelo PID

Tags: python, windows, processo

Bom Dia!

Estou montando um script em Python para monitorar uma determinada tarefa do windows pelo PID, para isso estou utilizando a biblioteca Psutil do Python.

O problema é que, sempre que rodo o código ele trás o status da tarefa como **running**, mesmo quando está tarefas esta travada no windows (Não esta respondendo).

Alguém sabe se tem outra maneira de sabe se a tarefa esta travada?

```
import psutil
import time
import smtplib
from Include import TC_Email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import datetime

time.sleep(15)
print(datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
validacao_processo = False

for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username', 'status']):

    #print(proc.info)

    if  proc.info['name'] == 'GERENCIADORTAREFAA_0002_0005_0307.EXE':         # 'chrome.exe': ; 'GERENCIADORTAREFAA_0002_0005_0307.EXE': ; 'pycharm64.exe': ; 'sisloga_0002_0005_1583.EXE':

        validacao_processo = True
        pid_number = proc.info['pid']

        p = psutil.Process(pid = pid_number)
        with p.oneshot():

            status = p.status()                                                                                     # Status do processo
            memory_uses = str(round(p.memory_percent(memtype='rss') + p.memory_percent(memtype='vms'), 2))          # Uso da memoria pelo processo
            memory_porcentagem_uses = str(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)                                          # Porcentagem total da memoria usada
            cpu_uses = str(sum(p.cpu_times()[:2]))                                                                  # Porcentagem total da CPU pelo processo
            cpu_freq = str(round(psutil.cpu_freq().current / 1000, 1))                                              # Frequencia da CPU

            print(proc.as_dict(attrs=['status']))
            print(proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid']))
            print(proc.as_dict(attrs=['name']))
            print(datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

            # print(pid_number)
            # print(proc.info['name'])
            # print(status)
            # print(memory_uses)
            # print(memory_porcentagem_uses)
            # print(cpu_uses)
            # print(cpu_freq)

            if status != 'running':

                subject = 'Attention - Gerenciador de Tarefas'
                msg = 'Hello Word! \n\n' \
                      '\n' \
                      'The ESL - Gerenciador de Tarefas isn`t running, please check it. ' \
                      '\n\n\n' \
                      'More information about it:' \
                      '\n\n' \
                      f'- PID: {str(pid_number)} \n- Process ' + proc.info['name'] +' \n- Status: ' + status + ' \n- Memory Usage: ' + memory_uses + \
                      '%\n- Total Memory Usage: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '%\n- CPU Usage: ' + cpu_uses + ' \n- Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + 'GHz\n- Log: ' + TC_Email.status_email + ' - ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

                #TC_Email.send_email(subject, msg)

                arquivo_log = open('log.txt', 'a')
                arquivo_log.writelines('\nPID: ' + str(pid_number) +'          Process ' + proc.info['name'] +'          Status: ' + status + '          Memory Usage: ' + memory_uses + \
                                       '%          Total Memory Usage: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '%          CPU Usage: ' + cpu_uses + '%          Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + 'GHz          Log: ' + TC_Email.status_email + ' - ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
                arquivo_log.close()

                break

            else:

                arquivo_log = open('log.txt', 'a')
                arquivo_log.writelines('\nPID: ' + str(pid_number) +'          Process ' + proc.info['name'] +'          Status: ' + status + '          Memory Usage: ' + memory_uses + \
                                       '%          Total Memory Usage: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '%          CPU Usage: ' + cpu_uses + '%          Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + 'GHz          Log: ' + TC_Email.status_email + ' - ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
                arquivo_log.close()

                break


if validacao_processo == False:

    memory_porcentagem_uses = str(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)              # Porcentagem total da memoria usada
    cpu_uses = str(sum(psutil.cpu_times()[:2]))                                 # Porcentagem total da CPU pelo processo
    cpu_freq = str(round(psutil.cpu_freq().current / 1000, 1))                  # Frequencia da CPU

    subject = 'Attention - Gerenciador de Tarefas'
    msg = 'Hello Word! \n\n' \
          '\n' \
          'The ESL - Gerenciador de Tarefas isn`t task fould, please check it. ' \
          '\n\n\n' \
          'More information about it:' \
          '\n\n' \
          '- Process: GERENCIADORTAREFAA_0002_0005_0307.EXE' + '%\n- Total Memory Usage: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '%\n- CPU Usage: ' + cpu_uses + \
          '%\n- Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + '%\n- Log: ' + TC_Email.status_email + ' - ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

    #TC_Email.send_email(subject, msg)

    arquivo_log = open('log.txt', 'a')
    arquivo_log.writelines('\nTotal Memory Usage: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '%          CPU Usage: ' + cpu_uses + '          Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + '          Log: ' + TC_Email.status_email + ' - ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
    arquivo_log.close()

    print('- Frequencia CPU: ' + cpu_freq + ' GHz \n- Consumo Memoria: ' + memory_porcentagem_uses + '\n- Consumo CPU: ' + cpu_uses)
```